# How to install VBA-AddIn from VSTO and call macros

Tags: excel, vsto, vba

I have `*.xlam` file with **VBA-macros** and **VSTO** with flexible ribbon.
I want to install **VBA-AddIn** from **VSTO** and then call **VBA-macros**, but when I try this code macros become available only after restart Excel application. Is it possible to make available macros without restart?

```
    var addin = appExcel.AddIns.Add(addinPath, false);

    foreach (Excel.AddIn addIn in appExcel.AddIns)
    {
        if (addIn.Name.Contains("VbaLibName"))
        {
            addIn.Installed = true;
        }
    }

    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Run(macroName);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, that this behavior was caused by an exception. I tried to call this code in ThisAddIn_Startup, and application doesn't have any opened workbooks.
I solved problem by this line of code before adding addin.

```
    Excel.Workbook wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Add();
```

Comment: it is the same as trying to set calculation options. if you dont have any open workbook you'll get an exception.